# break line in if condition using algpseudocode while having nice indentation

Tags: line-breaking, algorithmicx

I am trying to split a long line in my algorithm, which is in my if condition into two lines, while maintaining indentation. AND I don't want the line break to be anywhere but after my -or- in the code.

SO here is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algnewcommand\algorithmicor{\textbf{or}}
\newcommand{\pushcode}[1][1]{\hskip\dimexpr#1\algorithmicindent\relax}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\caption{Core genome identification}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
%I tired using this push
\While{$list$ is not empty \algorithmicor \\ \pushcode[1] second condition} 
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I have tried it with this push for example, but this gives me a new line number what I don't want!

And other suggestions like defining

```
 \newcommand{\myindent}[1]{
 \newline\makebox[#1]{}
 }
```

Also puts the indent on a spec. indentation, what is not what I am searching for. I want it to be at the same indentation as the condition before. So something like

```
if (this is my first condition OR
    this is the second)
```

Answer (score 4):

Redefine the *loop* and *if* statements in the preamble (after `\usepackage{algpseudocode}`) as follows:

```
\newcommand\CONDITION[2]%
   {\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1#2\end{tabular}}
\algdef{SE}[WHILE]{While}{EndWhile}[1]%
   {\algorithmicwhile\ \CONDITION{#1}{\ \algorithmicdo}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicwhile}
\algdef{SE}[FOR]{For}{EndFor}[1]%
   {\algorithmicfor\ \CONDITION{#1}{\ \algorithmicdo}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForAll}[1]%
   {\algorithmicforall\ \CONDITION{#1}{\ \algorithmicdo}}
\algdef{SE}[REPEAT]{Repeat}{Until}%
   {\algorithmicrepeat}[1]%
   {\algorithmicuntil\ \CONDITION{#1}{}}
\algdef{SE}[IF]{If}{EndIf}[1]%
   {\algorithmicif\ \CONDITION{#1}{\ \algorithmicthen}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}
\algdef{C}[IF]{IF}{ElsIf}[1]%
   {\algorithmicelse\ \algorithmicif\ \CONDITION{#1}{\ \algorithmicthen}}
\makeatletter
\ifthenelse{\equal{\ALG@noend}{t}}%
   {\algtext*{EndWhile}%
    \algtext*{EndFor}%
    \algtext*{EndLoop}%
    \algtext*{EndIf}%
   }{}%
\makeatother
```

The definitions are taken from the style file `algpseudocode.sty` and modified to handle multiline conditions.

Here is a complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\newcommand\CONDITION[2]%
   {\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1#2\end{tabular}}
\algdef{SE}[WHILE]{While}{EndWhile}[1]%
   {\algorithmicwhile\ \CONDITION{#1}{\ \algorithmicdo}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicwhile}
\algdef{SE}[FOR]{For}{EndFor}[1]%
   {\algorithmicfor\ \CONDITION{#1}{\ \algorithmicdo}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}
\algdef{S}[FOR]{ForAll}[1]%
   {\algorithmicforall\ \CONDITION{#1}{\ \algorithmicdo}}
\algdef{SE}[REPEAT]{Repeat}{Until}%
   {\algorithmicrepeat}[1]%
   {\algorithmicuntil\ \CONDITION{#1}{}}
\algdef{SE}[IF]{If}{EndIf}[1]%
   {\algorithmicif\ \CONDITION{#1}{\ \algorithmicthen}}%
   {\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}
\algdef{C}[IF]{IF}{ElsIf}[1]%
   {\algorithmicelse\ \algorithmicif\ \CONDITION{#1}{\ \algorithmicthen}}
\makeatletter
\ifthenelse{\equal{\ALG@noend}{t}}%
   {\algtext*{EndWhile}%
    \algtext*{EndFor}%
    \algtext*{EndLoop}%
    \algtext*{EndIf}%
   }{}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \While{short condition} 
  \EndWhile
  \While{very long condition\\broken into two lines} 
  \EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```